# Нехватка памяти?

Tags: java, android

Имеется 5 картинок помещенных    в GrieView, но страницка не открывается сразу краш .Это на эмуляторах а на реальном девайсе все работает .Как это понять ? вот такую ошибку дает студиа

> 11-16 04:03:41.564 1852-1852/com.example.elvir.premiumdental E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.elvir.premiumdental, PID: 1852
>                                                                                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>                                                                                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
>                                                                                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
>                                                                                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
>                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
>                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
>                                                                                      at com.example.elvir.premiumdental.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:56)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:421)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1233)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: А картинки грузите как? Используете библиотеки какие-нибудь? Например Glide, Piicasso?

Comment: да нет вроде они в дравбле находятся потому и непонятна ошибка я ведь делал так и с 15 картинками проблем небыло а щас такое )

Comment: А размеры у них какие? Можно с этими либами из ресурсов попробывать загрузить

Comment: нищие по 300 кб )с))

Answer (score 2):

Да, вполне возможно нехватка памяти при декодировании картинки. Рекомендуется:

1. Использовать LRU кеш;
2. Сжимать каждую картики ровно под размер экрана;
3. Уменьшить количество байт под цвет. Так смена ARGB_8888 на RGB_565 позволит сэкономить память в 2 раза;